# insert into 2 joined tables in a single effecient query with mssql

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-insert

I am trying to insert some data into 2 different tables in my ms sql database (ms sql server 2012).

Consider the following 2 tables, that contains information about polls and their choices.

```
+----------------+ 
|     Polls      |
+----------------+
| pollID         | The id of a poll (auto increment)
| memberID       | The id of the member, owning the poll
| pollTitle      | The title/question of the poll
| date           | The date of the poll
+----------------+

+----------------+ 
|  PollChoices   |
+----------------+
| pollChoiceID   | The id of a poll choice (auto increment)
| pollID         | The id of the poll, that include this choice
| pollChoice     | The name/title of the poll choice
+----------------+
```

How can I make a query, inserting the data in the most effecient way?
I can always make 2 queries, but can't really figure out how to do it with a single one.

Óne of the main issues for me in this case is getting the id of the poll when inserting the pollchoices.. how can i get this newly inserted "pollID" (auto increment) and use it in the same query?

Also, is it neccesary to make use of transactions or stored procedures (I've read this somewhere)?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you are aking is possible.

The best way I think to perform the operation you describe, is to *wrap it inside a stored procedure*. You can use [SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) to get the ID of the previously added record and a TRANSACTION together with a [TRY-CATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) block to ensure that *both insert queries are executed or none at all*.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertPoll] ( 
-- sproc declaration here, including the following parameters:  
-- @memberID, @pollTitle, @date, @pollChoiceID, @pollChoice
)
AS BEGIN

   DECLARE @pollID INT

   BEGIN TRANSACTION;

   BEGIN TRY

      INSERT INTO Polls (memberID, pollTitle, date)
      VALUES (@memberID, @pollTitle, @date)

      -- Get the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope
      SET @pollID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

      INSERT INTO PollChoices(pollChoiceID, pollID, pollChoice )
      VALUES (@pollChoiceID, @pollID, @pollChoice)

   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
      IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;            
   END CATCH;

   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
      COMMIT TRANSACTION; 
END
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much. +1! I didn't need the "Create procedure" part though, but what is the purpose of this?

Comment: @user68621 The purpose of it is to create a stored procedure (in case you want such a thing). For docu on sprocs have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

Comment: I know this may be a "noobish" question, but is it possible to return the pollID as a resultset after the "COMMIT TRANSACTION" part.

Comment: Yes it is possible to return the value of pollID: RETURN @pollID should work. You may as well have a look here http://www.sqlteam.com/article/stored-procedures-returning-data

Comment: Thanks for your help.. But I cant seem to get it to work. It is not returning anything. Can you see whats wrong: http://pastebin.com/39B01iC4

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
declare @npi int
INSERT INTO Polls (memberID, pollTitle, date)
 VALUES (@memberID, @pollTitle, @date)
set @npi=
(select top 1 PollId
from Polls
order by PollId desc)
INSERT INTO PollChoices(pollChoiceID, pollID, pollChoice )
   VALUES (@pollChoiceID, @npi, @pollChoice)
```